# Separating vector on dense subalgebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $M$ be a vN algebra and $U$ be a S.O.T dense self-adjoint subalgebra of $M$ has separating vector, does $M$ have? If not give a counterexample. Or there is a condition on M like type II_{1} or hyperfinite II_{1} factors the result will be true?